# Run python script to monitor ftp folder and plot data extracted from each new file as it appears

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script which extracts binary data from a file and plots it , I want to run it to watch an ftp folder and then extract and plot data from each new file as they appear in that folder.

so far I have tried:

```
from ftplib import FTP
from time import sleep

def monitor(server, directory, interval):

  ftp = FTP(server)
  ftp.login('display' '')
  ftp.cwd(directory)

  old_files = []
    try:
        while True:
            new_files = ftp.nlst()
            #print(new_files)
            if len(old_files) != 0 and new_files != old_files:
              changes = [i for i in new_files if i not in old_files]
              print(changes)
        old_files = new_files
        sleep(interval)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
    ftp.quit()


monitor('10.34.34.34', directory='/var/gunlink/segdfiles/M18A1045BS5038', interval =10 )
```

But the problem is that it doesn't display any changes I am not sure what I am doing in-correctly.

Comment: Well, for one thing you're never updating `old_files`.

Comment: @cody I have updated the code , but depending on the interval I sometime get two files , sometimes one , is there a way to just take the latest file.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a timestamp compared with file modified time.
Say for example you are polling and you need to fetch the files which have been modified/created less than 5 mins ago you would modify your function as below:

```
def monitor(server, directory, interval):

    ftp = FTP(server)
    ftp.login('display' '')
    ftp.cwd(directory)
    previous_timestamp = time.time()
    _files = []
    try:
        while True:
            for attrs, _file in zip(ftp.listdir_attr(ftp.pwd), ftp.listdir()):
                time_diff = datetime.fromtimestamp(previous_timestamp) - 
                datetime.fromtimestamp(attrs.st_mtime)
                    if (time_diff.total_seconds()/60)>5:
                        continue
                    else:
                        _files.append(_file)

            time.sleep(interval)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ftp.quit()
```